# Is there a pre-styled Omega subtheme out there?

Tags: theming

I am after a theme that looks good out of the box and I don't need to make a lot of theming changes. The customer is not fussed about the styling but obviously doesn't want a stark/bare looking site either. The omega theme fits the bill functionality wise, it's responsive and the regions/sections suit us. However, it is way too bare/stark. I've so far tried Omega kickstart, omega and omega-alpha.

Any suggestions on a pre styled free theme I can used that is based on the Omega "framework"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/1298632) is the complete listing of themes which uses the omega theme as a base theme.

Apart from that you can get the list of various themes/sites which uses omega theme on [omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme project page

Comment: Thank you @mohit_rocks

I ended up going with the corporate clean theme, but it does not offer as many grids as the omega does. Or maybe I just don't know how to get to them? There are not as many sections/regions as there are in Omega :(